# Does AGPL 3 requeired to give free services

Tags: open-source-software, gpl

I found the following lines about AGPL3 and I am not sure about the correct way to interpret it.

Does AGPL3 oblige me to give my cloud services that connected to the app for free or is it only the source code of it.

They write the word `source` all the time and it sounds to me like it does not have to be the word `source code` and could be the actual service.

Source one [gnu](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html)

> access to copy the Corresponding Source from a network server at no
> charge.

> e) Convey the object code using peer-to-peer transmission, provided
> you inform other peers where the object code and Corresponding Source
> of the work are being offered to the general public at no charge under
> subsection 6d.

> by providing access to the Corresponding Source from a network server
> at no charge,

Source two [synopsys](https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/software-security/agpl-affero-gpl-3/)

> [I]f you modify the Program, your modified version must prominently
> offer all users interacting with it remotely through a computer
> network…an opportunity to receive the Corresponding Source of your
> version by providing access to the Corresponding Source from a network
> server at no charge, through some standard or customary means of
> facilitating copying of software.

Example:

I use app on the mobile with AGPL3.

This app is using google Firebase cloud that cost me money each month to use.

Do I need to provide this service for free, or am I allowed take money on it every month to for maintenance of the application.

Share the code that I put to the cloud I understand that I need, but can am I allowed to charge the users for the service of using the cloud.

Comment: The term Corresponding Source is defined in the license (section 1). It means “all the **source code** needed to generate, install, and (for an executable work) run the object code and to modify the work, including scripts to control those activities.” The only service you have to perform is providing this source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, commercial use is allowed for the AGPLv3 license. You can charge for your use of the software so long as you provide a way for the public to download the source code in its entirety.

Comment: Strictly speaking, isn't “the public” just current and former users?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - Yes, the license only requires you to provide the source to those who have access to the binaries (or in this case, the web service).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Not necessarily, you don't have to be a "user", I could, as a non user, request the source code covered under AGPLv3. I don't have to participate in or even use in any way the software to be able to request the code.

Comment: @RonBeyer You can also request the code of proprietary systems, even if you don't use them.

Comment: Right, but you aren't entitled to it, whereas with the AGPL the requestor must be provided the code, regardless of being a user or not. That's what I mean by "public", anybody capable of requesting it must be provided the source. It isn't the license holders right to discriminate in favor of users.

Comment: @RonBeyer The license says "all users interacting with it remotely through a computer network". If you don't interact with it remotely through a computer network (and don't receive a copy of the binary, etc etc) then you aren't entitled to the source code. In practice, you can get a copy from someone who does interact with it. So most vendors using AGPLv3 find it easiest to just give the software to everyone, no limitations, rather than restricting it to users.

Comment: I haven't checked the AGPL, but with GPL I can distribute the software together with the source code (at the same time), and if I do that for all distributions of that software then I don't have any obligation to give the source code to anyone else. For example a contractor can build software derived from GPL-licensed code and hand the product _with source code_ to their client, and there is no further obligation. Of course the client can pass the application and source code on to anyone.